# KeyFrames revert themselves (CSS)

Tags: css, animation, transform, keyframe

So as a practice i tried myself on a simple animation: A snake (like in the game) sorrounding the login-screen i made. I want it to just go form position A-->B-->C-->D.

The KeyFrames i used are as follow:

```
@keyframes snake{

    0%{
        left: 10%;
        top: 100px;
    }

    25%{
        transform: translateX(1500px);
    }

    50%{
        transform: translateY(1000px);     
    }
    75%{
        transform: translateX(-1500px)
    }
    100%{

        transform: translateY(-1000px);
         }
```

The snake class:

```
.snake{

    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid red;
    left: 10%;
    top: 100px;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-name: snake;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;

}
```

Problem is that when a keyFrame has ended it reverts its position again. Meaning after going to the right of the screen it goes diagonally from the top-right to the bottom-left.

I'd appreciate any help. I dont think that any of the other code is causing a problem but if need be just tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to combine the `translateX` and `translateY` together. Applying only one means that the other is `0` which create the issue.

Example:

```css
@keyframes snake {
  25% {
    transform: translate(150px,0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(150px,100px);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(-100px,100px)
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-100px,-100px);
  }
}

.snake {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid red;
  left: 10%;
  top: 100px;
  animation: snake 5s infinite alternate linear;
}
```

```html
<div class="snake"></div>
```